# Django Tastypie create API which accepts POST data but not creates any entry in database

Tags: python, django, tastypie

My question is exactly what it's subject says :
How to create Django Tastypie API which accepts the POST data, does some processing on it and returns some HTTP response, but does not creates any entry in database.
For Example for this sample API resource :

```
class NextNumberResource(ModelResource):
class Meta:
    resource_name = 'next_number'
    detail_allowed_methods = []
    list_allowed_methods = ['post']


def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):

    #raise CustomBadRequest(code = "code ={c}".format(c=int(bundle.data["number"])*2))
    next_number = int(bundle.data["number"]) * 2
    data = json.dumps({"next_number":next_number})
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json', status=200)
```

I am getting following error : 
**{"error_message": "'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'pk'"}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to handle this request in dispatch_* methods (e.g. dispatch_list).

For example [here](https://github.com/Alexx-G/tastypie-example/blob/master/src/cars/api/resources.py#L9).

Explanation: If you handle a post request which doesn't create any instance, you have to process it before std workflow of the tastypie.

Comment: The link to the file on Github is now dead. This is why it is recommended to post contents from the link *in the answer itself*, to protect it in case the link dies.